# Problems in gdalwarp

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-processing

I was trying to use gdalwarp inside a qgis 2.0 model via processing but I think that the implementation is not working properly. So I would like to know if anyone has encountered this problem?

[image]

Comment: Specifically, what was the problem?

Comment: If you're convinced you've found a new bug, just report it on the bug tracker. See http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Bugreports but be sure to provide more detail than you've added here.

Comment: Qgis craches when I try to edit the algorithm.

Comment: This is the first problem. If I put zero in Additional creation parameters and I try to edit again the algorithm it craches

Comment: have you tried running `gdalwarp` from the command line to see if you can identify if the problem is due to the input, parameters or QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Please see http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9109

until fixed the workaroud is to add in the model a (empty) string parameter and use it in "additional creation parameters" of the model.